# Why is my TableViewController only returning a single collapsible section?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I am using a `UITableViewController` to try and return a series of data, each with their own collapsible section, similarly to below.

[Example Table View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irRkj.png)

I have added two separate header sections ("Item 1") and ("Item 2") respectively, however only 'Item 2" is being returned and available to select, whereas the 'Item" section isn't appearing.

Here is the code I am using to show the sections:

```
    var tableViewData = [cellData]()

    self.tableViewData = [cellData(opened: false, title: "Item 1", sectionData: [productName1 ?? "test?"])]
                            
    self.tableViewData = [cellData(opened: false, title: "Item 2", sectionData: [productName2 ?? "test"])]
```

Here is the code I am using to programmatically alter the sections (to update the number of results under each section).

```
        override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return tableViewData.count
    }
    

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if tableViewData[section].opened == true {
            return tableViewData[section].sectionData.count + 1
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var dataIndex = indexPath.row - 1
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {return UITableViewCell()}
            
            cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title
            
            return cell
              
            
        } else {
            
            
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {return UITableViewCell()}
            
            cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[indexPath.row - 1]
              
            return cell
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
        if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)
        } else {
            tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)
        }
        }
    }
```

Why is only one of the selectable sections appearing once the app is run, when two have been added ("Item 1" and "Item 2"? *Please find below a screenshot from the app for a visual example of how the page currently looks.*

[In app demonstration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU9pv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't actually added two sections -- you've one added item and then replaced it with another:

```
    var tableViewData = [cellData]()

    self.tableViewData = [cellData(opened: false, title: "Item 1", sectionData: [productName1 ?? "test?"])] //this is the first assignment
                            
    self.tableViewData = [cellData(opened: false, title: "Item 2", sectionData: [productName2 ?? "test"])] //then, you overwrite it here
```

Instead, you could do this:

```
self.tableViewData = 
   [cellData(opened: false, title: "Item 1", sectionData: [productName1 ?? "test?"]), 
    cellData(opened: false, title: "Item 2", sectionData: [productName2 ?? "test"])]
```